# how to measure python asyncio event loop metrics?

Tags: python-asyncio, metrics

Is there a module to measure asyncio event loop metrics? or for asyncio event loop, what metrics we should monitor for performance analysis purpose?

e.g.

- how many tasks in the event loop?
- how many tasks in waiting states?

I'm not trying to measure the coroutine functions. aiomonitor has the functionality, but is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly believe number of pending tasks or tasks summary will tell you much. Let's say you have 10000 tasks, 8000 of them pending: is it much, is it not? Who knows.

Thing is - each `asyncio` task (or any other Python object) can consume different amount of different machine resources.

Instead of trying to monitor `asyncio` specific objects I think it's better to monitor general metrics:

- CPU usage
- RAM usage
- Network I/O (in case you're dealing with it)
- Hard drive I/O  (in case you're dealing with it)

What comes to `asyncio` you should probably always use [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) to limit max number of currently running jobs and implement a convenient way to change value of semaphore(s) (for example, through config file).

It'll allow to alter workload on a concrete machine depending on its available and actually utilized resources.

**Upd:**

> My question, will asyncio still accept new connections during this
>   block?

If your event loop is blocked by some CPU calculation, `asyncio` will start to process new connections later - when event loop is free again (if they're not time-outed at this moment).

**You should always avoid situation of freezing event loop.** Freezed somewhere event loop means that all tasks everywhere in code are freezed also! Any kind of loop freezing breaks whole idea of using asynchronous approach regardless of number of tasks. Any kind of code, where event loop is freezed will have performance issues.

As you noted, you can use `ProcessPoolExecutor` with [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to await for CPU-bound stuff, but you can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to avoid freezing as well.

Comment: I have a REST service based on Sanic which uses asyncio + uvloop. An endpoint handler will call a couple of coroutines for a request, but one coroutine is CPU-bound, may take 1 second. Asyncio event loop is blocked when this coroutine is running. My question, will asyncio still accept new connections during this block? Th at's why I think # of tasks in the event loop may give me an answer. I knew that CPU-bound task should be executed in a ProcessPool. I'm trying to explain the behavior our current server which runs CPU-bound task in event loop.

Comment: @Bewang I updated answer adding info about what you ask.